# SAM API Gateway caching with a method with query parameters

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, serverless-application-model

With the following SAM template:

```
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - HttpMethod: GET
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 120
          ResourcePath: "/getData"
          CachingEnabled: true
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        basePath: /Prod
        info:
          title: OutService
        x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: "*"
              Action: execute-api:Invoke
              Resource:
                - execute-api:/*/*/*
        paths:
          "/getData":
            get:
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${OutLambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
      EndpointConfiguration: PRIVATE
      Cors:
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
```

Now /getData accepts query parameters e.g. - `/getData?path=abcd/efgh` with a response `1234`.

When I trigger the API with the path `/getData?path=abcd/efgh`, this is cached correctly - responds with `1234`.

However, after I trigger the api with different query params - e.g. `/getData?path=uvw/xyz` expecting the respons `789` the response cached for the first request is returned - `1234`.

How can I make sure that the caching is applied for paths with query params?

***Example of a sequence of issued requests and their respective responses:***

`/getData?path=abcd/efgh` -> `1234` is returned and cached at 11:01:01

`/getData?path=uvw/xyz` -> `789` is returned and cached at 11:01:02

`/getData?path=abcd/efgh` -> `1234` is returned from the cache at 11:01:20

`/getData?path=uvw/xyz` -> `789` is returned from the cache at 11:01:31

**EDIT**

I am trying to utilise the `RequestParameters` and then map them to `CacheKeyParameters` as explained in these 2 articles - https://medium.com/@dougmoscrop/i-set-up-api-gateway-caching-here-are-some-things-that-surprised-me-7526d954fbe6 & https://theburningmonk.com/2016/04/serverless-enable-caching-on-query-string-parameters-in-api-gateway/, but both of these use the serverless framework I am unable to figure out how this would fit into my template

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The end result in the AWS API Gateway console must display that the set caching checkbox is:

[image]

We can achieve it like this:

```
Resources:
  MyApi:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Api
    Properties:
      StageName: Prod
      CacheClusterEnabled: true
      CacheClusterSize: '0.5'
      MethodSettings:
        - HttpMethod: GET
          CacheTtlInSeconds: 120
          ResourcePath: "/getData"
          CachingEnabled: true
      DefinitionBody:
        swagger: 2.0
        basePath: /Prod
        info:
          title: OutService
        x-amazon-apigateway-policy:
          Version: "2012-10-17"
          Statement:
            - Effect: Allow
              Principal: "*"
              Action: execute-api:Invoke
              Resource:
                - execute-api:/*/*/*
        paths:
          "/getData":
            get:
              # ** Missing param start **
              parameters:
                - name: "path"
                  in: "query"
                  required: "false"
                  type: "string"
              # ** Missing param end **
              x-amazon-apigateway-integration:
              # ** Key is cached **
                cacheKeyParameters:
                  - method.request.querystring.path
                httpMethod: POST
                type: aws_proxy
                uri:
                  Fn::Sub: arn:aws:apigateway:${AWS::Region}:lambda:path/2015-03-31/functions/${OutLambda.Arn}/invocations
              responses: {}
      EndpointConfiguration: PRIVATE
      Cors:
        AllowHeaders: "'*'"
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Additionally, one can check [CacheKeyParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-apitgateway-method-integration.html#cfn-apigateway-method-integration-cachekeyparameters) and [RequestParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-apigateway-method.html#cfn-apigateway-method-requestparameters) for more information and acceptable values